# Pandas to Spark DataFrame transform turning uuid strings into integers

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have a Pandas df with the following fields:

```
                                  survey_id  gender
0  000de5b8-651b-4a47-961c-548d80c84df2    Male
1  003e38f2-4196-4b10-9637-46774b21bcda    Male
2  00595d21-4c1a-469a-9724-804b7883822b  Female
3  0095bcd8-1184-41bc-8742-d14c3e3642c4    Male
4  00986df4-717c-4a6f-818b-a539a0b45fb2  Female
```

The `survey_id` is just a uuid. Here is the snippet of code creating a Spark DataFrame (in PySpark) from the pandas version:

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("survey_id", StringType()),
    StructField("gender", StringType()),
])

res = sql(survey_demos)[['survey_id', 'gender']]
self._survey_demographics = self._spark.createDataFrame(res, schema)
logging.info(self._survey_demographics.head(log))
logging.info(type(self._survey_demographics))
```

The function call `sql(survey_demos)` is querying a database and returning a Pandas df. Now, check out the logging output:

```
2016-08-18 09:39:11,795 root INFO [Row(survey_id='{__class__=uuid.UUID, int=72159140233069381076719472719973874}', gender='Male'), Row(survey_id='{__class__=uuid.UUID, int=323077413680511253270271409764023514}', gender='Male'), Row(survey_id='{__class__=uuid.UUID, int=464003322584728470087346523203666475}', gender='Female'), Row(survey_id='{__class__=uuid.UUID, int=777482443631412718495518514480562884}', gender='Male'), Row(survey_id='{__class__=uuid.UUID, int=791459271937809735598486155808759730}', gender='Female')]
2016-08-18 09:39:11,795 root INFO <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>
```

What is Spark doing here, and why does it not just give me a `StringType`
 as I specified in the schema?

Comment: Schema is a declaration of what-is not casting instruction. In other words schema should match data not the other way around. But it looks like you actually have strings here.

Comment: Well, I "fixed" this by explicitly casting as CHAR(32) in my sql query. But that doesn't really answer this particular question.